# How to handle double questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

This [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-go-to-manchester-from-london#comment7443_1475), was asking two unrelated questions:

1. How to go to Manchester from London?
2. Is there any 3g data package that works across Europe?

Unfortunately, there is no option to move answers from one question to another and some answers answer both questions. I split this off into a [separate question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/is-there-any-3g-data-package-that-works-across-europe), but this has now been marked as an [exact duplicate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/choices-for-prepaid-gsm-data-with-laptop-tethering-in-europe). From the current situation, how should we resolve this mess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in future they should just be flagged ASAP and closed.  There's no way even for us moderators to split them, and once the OP has been notified that his question is closed, he can reword and flag for reopening, or reword and raise a second question if he sees fit.

Also you'll notice that your new question is a duplicate of [Choices for prepaid GSM data with laptop tethering in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/choices-for-prepaid-gsm-data-with-laptop-tethering-in-europe), which is an unfortunate coincidence.

What we could do in this case is remove all references to the 3g stuff, and just leave the Manchester details in the original question, or just revert and then close the original question, as it's been answered and can now be left alone.

Comment: +1. I'm for reverting to old question and closing it, so that the helpful answers remain. Multiple questions in one can be something we'll be more careful about in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If only one of the questions has been answered so far, edit the other part out. Leave a comment to explain what you've done, telling the asker to repost the other part as a separate question. Something like:

> Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/about). Please post one question at a time. I've edited your post to include just one question, which already had answers. Feel free to post your other question separately.

If one of the questions is off-topic, remove it and don't suggest to repost it, but still leave a comment to explain what you've done and why the question is off-topic.